# SQL - how to add more than one value to single row?

Tags: android, sql, insert

I need to create a method which will create a table and one row.

Inside this row, I want to put about five things.

For example:

I want to make an database that stores things inside our pencil-case.

Let's assume we have in our pencil-case couple of things pencil, pen, crayon.

It should be stored like:

```
Table name - Pencil_case
Row name - stored_things
```

In "stored_things," we should add things that we have in pencil-case.

I tried with ContentValues, but I can't enter more than one value.

How can I add more than one value in single row?

Keep that in mind, I want to do it inside the database class.

I don't want to get values from user.

As I said, I've already tried the ContentValues interface, and it looks like that:

```
    public boolean insertData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, "1");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, "2");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, "3");
   return db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  That's explicitly against how SQL and relational databases work.  You either need to have separately named columns, or you have a second table that maps rows of the first table to values of column 2 in a 1 to many fashion, and combine them with a join.

Alternatively you may, depending on the values, be able to hack it with something like comma separated values.  But doing so would render them unsearchable.

Comment: But i was opened my database in some sql program,and i just typed query like insert into TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) values ("a","b","c") and it worked. But i wasn't sure how i can move this query into android.

Comment: You can't put more than one value in a column.  That isn't valid sql.  You can have multiple columns, but 1 column=1 value.

Comment: So.. If i want to store in database those "things" that i actually got in pencil-case i should do separately rows like 
Table name: pencil-case
Row name: firstThing with value pencil
Row name: secondThing value pen etc?